# hwe-support-status is not quite working

Tags: kernel, hardware-enablement-stack

I can understand **why** this is happening. The problem is that it is not able to complete. There is an "unmet dependency" which I am not able to resolve. Any hints?

Here are some screenshots:

update-manager

[image: update-manager]

update-manager greyed out immediately after clicking "Install..."
[image: update-manager greyed out immediately after clicking "Install..."]

"Package dependencies cannot be resolved"
[image: "Package dependencies cannot be resolved"]

"unmet dependencies" message
[image: "unmet dependencies" message]

Comment: From https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack, try `sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-core-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-xenial libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-xenial`.

Comment: Thanks @edwinksl. Here's the result: http://pastebin.com/FSGZTeDW

Comment: Hmm, I see some `i386` packages listed. Can you try the command given in "MULTIARCH DESKTOP" in the link I gave?

Comment: Yes I saw that option last night, but at the time I couldn't make head nor tail of it. When I looked at it again today, it made sense, so I used the command. I used it as published on https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack, and watched it all happen in front of me. It resulted in a lengthy process with quite a few steps, and the new kernel build seemed to go OK. Unfortunately, however, now I boot into a blank screen. I have tried removing all video drivers (except X driver), because it looked like an earlier video driver problem that I had one time. No luck I'm afraid.

Comment: A couple of hours messing about, switching to the X.org driver, removing Nvidia driver 352, installing Nvidia driver 340, and I am able to use the computer again. I can't use the GPU for calculations, because something's still wrong and I can't install Nvidia CUDA software as a result, but this is better than the last time I posted.

Comment: This question is no longer relevant, because this morning I took the plunge and went ahead with the distribution upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04. For the first time, I am still able to use the computer after a distribution upgrade. That has never happened before. For each of 10.04 to 12.04, and 12.04 to 14.04, the upgrade process didn't work properly and I ended up having to do a fresh installation from a downloaded image. I meticulously noted every single change I ever made to my 14.04 installation from the day I installed it onwards. Somehow, I lost those notes within the last 6 months.

Comment: So without my notes for a clean install, and two bad experiences using the distribution upgrade, I was very reluctant to go from 14.04 to 16.04. However, so far, so good.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it sorted out in the end. :) Anyway, if you believe this question is no longer relevant, you could delete it. On the other hand, if you think you had a solution that worked, you could post it.